# POSTGIS UPDATE from self with left join

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a working SELECT statement but as SQL isn't my strong point I don't know how to make this into an UPDATE function. I have others that work but it appears to be JOIN's getting me here.

I've tried a few ways I could think of:
UPDATE ptp_links SET geom = ST_MAKELINE (this results in every record getting the same line)
UPDATE FROM SELECT (this one gets me the close but throws an error about column "geom" is of type geometry but expression is of type record)

This is my SELECT Query:

```
SELECT 
  ST_MAKELINE(
    ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326),
    ST_POINT(CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
      THEN in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
      ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION
    END,
    CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
      THEN in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
      ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION
    END, 4326)
  )
FROM ptp_links ptp
LEFT JOIN base_stations in_bs ON ptp.in_base_station = in_bs.id
LEFT JOIN base_stations out_bs ON ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id;
```

What I want to do is write the generated line from ST_MAKELINE back to the ptp_links table into the column called geom if anyone knows how I would do this in PostGIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can lean on [implicit joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html#TUTORIAL-JOIN) in a standard [`update..from..where`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.183.8):

> When a `FROM` clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the *`from_item`* list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table.

[Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/7V91jgyU)

```sql
UPDATE ptp_links AS ptp
SET geom = ST_MAKELINE(
                ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION,
                         out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                         4326),
                ST_POINT(CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
                              THEN in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
                              ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION END,
                         CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
                              THEN in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
                              ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION END, 
                         4326)
            )
FROM base_stations in_bs,
     base_stations out_bs
WHERE ptp.in_base_station  = in_bs.id
AND   ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id
RETURNING ptp.id,in_base_station,out_base_station,link_purpose,st_astext(geom);
```

| id | in_base_station | out_base_station | link_purpose | st_astext |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | backhaul | LINESTRING(2 1,0 0) |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | backhaul | LINESTRING(3 2,2 1) |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | other | LINESTRING(4 3,17 23) |

If you also grab some unique identifier from `ptp_links`, you can wrap your `select` in a [`with` CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) and use it as a source for the `update` statement: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3_vz97hl)

```sql
WITH update_batch AS (
    SELECT ptp.id,--something unique to targeted record
      ST_MAKELINE(
        ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION,
                 out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                 4326),
        ST_POINT(CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
          THEN in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
          ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION
        END,
        CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
          THEN in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
          ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION
        END, 4326)
      ) AS new_geom
    FROM ptp_links ptp
    LEFT JOIN base_stations in_bs ON ptp.in_base_station = in_bs.id
    LEFT JOIN base_stations out_bs ON ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id )
UPDATE ptp_links AS t
SET geom = new_geom
FROM update_batch AS s
WHERE s.id = t.id
RETURNING t.id,in_base_station,out_base_station,link_purpose,st_astext(geom);
```

Another way to wrap your base query is by making it a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) fed directly to the `update...set geom=` assignment: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/YxpAtq5x)

```sql
UPDATE ptp_links AS target
SET geom = (SELECT ST_MAKELINE(
                ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION,
                         out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 
                         4326),
                ST_POINT(CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
                  THEN in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
                  ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION
                END,
                CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
                  THEN in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION
                  ELSE ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION
                END, 4326)
              ) AS new_geom
            FROM ptp_links ptp
            LEFT JOIN base_stations in_bs ON ptp.in_base_station = in_bs.id
            LEFT JOIN base_stations out_bs ON ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id 
            WHERE ptp.id=target.id
            LIMIT 1 );
```

Note that in the last two cases you need to direct the incoming value to the target row by comparing a unique identifier. As [reminded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202385/postgis-update-from-self-with-left-join/77203821#comment136103714_77202441) by [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), if you don't have one, there's always the ["hidden" `ctid` column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html#DDL-SYSTEM-COLUMNS-CTID) you can use. Just keep in mind that `ctid` is stable throughout a single query but it's not guaranteed to stay consistent between separate, even consecutive queries.

Comment: If there's no unique column to use as a key, the [`ctid` system column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html) always works for this use case

Comment: Thank you, I knew why I was getting my result but could not find the way around it. ptp_links table does have a pk of id so I can use the other examples however so that I/others can follow it after coming back to it months/years later I went with the first example. Will also only ever be updating a single row at a time now that I have run the initial batch.

Comment: @Zegarek To use the first example in a trigger would I just change SET NEW.geom = ST_MAKELINE()
then replace all ptp. with NEW. in the CASE, WHERE, AND clauses?

Comment: If that's a trigger firing on insert or update to the `ptp_links`, you can simply override the fields of `new` record, then `return new`, without actually issuing an update statement. An update issued from a trigger that fires on updates could actually get you into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Zegarek didn't notice until today but this fails for any record where ptp.link_purpose is not equal to 'backhaul' (for us only a handful of records) as in that instance there is no value in the ptp.in_base_station column. So I changed to use your second solution that that works as thanks to the LEFT JOIN allowing NULL values rather than filtering by implicit joins. ptp does have an id column so was able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the approach shown by @Zegarek, you can first rewrite your query to use subqueries instead of (left) joins:

```
SELECT ST_MAKELINE(
  (
    SELECT ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326),
    FROM base_stations out_bs 
    WHERE ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id
  ),
  CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
    THEN (
      SELECT ST_POINT(in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326)
      FROM base_stations in_bs
      WHERE ptp.in_base_station = in_bs.id
    )
    ELSE ST_POINT(ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION, ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326)
  END
)
FROM ptp_links ptp;
```

Now it's easy to convert that into an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE ptp_links ptp
SET geom = ST_MAKELINE(
  (
    SELECT ST_POINT(out_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, out_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326),
    FROM base_stations out_bs 
    WHERE ptp.out_base_Station = out_bs.id
  ),
  CASE WHEN ptp.link_purpose = 'backhaul'
    THEN (
      SELECT ST_POINT(in_bs.longitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, in_bs.latitude::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326)
      FROM base_stations in_bs
      WHERE ptp.in_base_station = in_bs.id
    )
    ELSE ST_POINT(ptp.in_address_geo_x::DOUBLE PRECISION, ptp.in_address_geo_y::DOUBLE PRECISION, 4326)
  END
);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer its one I follow and was the path I was heading down when I posted the question.